# Creating a simple ruby project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jmeter, ruby-jmeter

Creating a ruby project

I am trying to create a simple ruby project to use the rubygem and ruby-jmeter, but unsure on how to proceed further. Below is the `github` of project.
https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter

//Below is my test.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ruby-jmeter'

test do
  threads count: 10 do
    visit name: 'Google Search', url: 'http://google.com'
  end
end.jmx
```

How can i creating a ruby project with needed gems, Its not a rails application.... a simple ruby project.

Comment: the require will work if you have your gem installed. You can install it using gem install <gem name>

Comment: By "project" do you mean a "script"? If you're using Ruby > 1.9 you don't need `require 'rubygems'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the way I would do it is first create a folder for your project and then run:

```
bundle init
```

Edit the Gemfile that was just created and make it look like this

```
# A sample Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "ruby-jmeter"
```

After this you run

```
bundle install
```

From now on you can run your ruby app with a `bundle exec` and it loads all the gems from your Gemfile. In addition to this if you provide a path like `bundle exec --path vendor/bundle` it will install the gems locally to the project so you keep the dependencies independent of your global ruby installation.

Comment: I am inside my project that is D:/project with a gem file... now how should i execute bundle exec --path vendor/bundle

Comment: You shouldn't need it. If you are in the project with the gemfile it should know to pick it up since it records where you installed your gems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bundler for this. Read "Getting Started" on http://bundler.io

In brief:

1. Create `Gemfile` with required gems
2. Run `bundle install`
3. Require `rubygems`, `bundler/setup` and all needed gems in your app.